# How to make several requests be made once? And the rest flow

Tags: jmeter

I have 2 queries and a db connection that i would like to make once as part of testing

1. CSRF
2. DB CONNECT
3. LOGIN

And then comes the API method I need that I'm testing. Here it needs to be run a number of times.
I read the documentation, but I still don't understand. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put them under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller), its children are being executed only during the 1st iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

---

I also see a number of [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) in your Test Plan, when you finish test development and debugging don't forget to remove them as they don't add any value and only consume resources, you should [execute your JMeter test plan in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) with all listeners disabled or deleted and once it's finished you can use Listeners to analyze the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) (or just [generate HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report) from it)

Comment: It worked thanks. But now there is a problem that it is not at the second time that my circle becomes empty XSRF. I get it from cookies and substitute it in the header.

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks again